# Counting highest number occurrences of character and return in separate data table/frame in R

Tags: r, sorting, count

I am looking for a string of code that will count the number of occurrences of a certain variable, sort it in order, and then limit it to the first X results. Example of what I am looking for:

Dataframe:

```
ID    Group
1000    A
1001    A
100a    A
100g    D
1004    C
100f    B
100z    B
1293    B
2412    B
3040    B
3452    C
```

Result: Table or Dataframe showing Top 3 results (of 4), in order of highest to low

```
Group   Count
B         5
A         3
C         2
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In `dplyr`, we can `count` `Group` values, select top 3 values and arrange them in decreasing order.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% count(Group) %>% top_n(3, n) %>% arrange(desc(n))

#  Group     n
#  <fct> <int>
#1 B         5
#2 A         3
#3 C         2
```

We can also use

```
df %>% count(Group) %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>% head(3)
```

---

Or in base R

```
stack(head(sort(table(df$Group), decreasing = TRUE), 3))
```